# php + mysql: is it safe to use serialize() without addslashes()?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Is it totally safe to insert array serialized with `serialize()` into db, or I should do `addslashes(serialize($array))` before? Or there can be some mysql specific characters? Can I delete data or whatever with insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is **not safe at all**.

And you should never use `addslashes` but `mysql_real_escape_string` instead. Or even better, use PDO with prepared statements instead of escaping.

Comment: **DO NOT USE `addslashes()`!** Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape your data for a MySQL database. Always.

Comment: ..unless you're using data-binding, or writing the data to something which is not mysql. Addslashes is always the wrong answer, mysql_real_escape_string() is not always the right one.

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:mysql], so in this case it is the correct answer.

Comment: You don't have to. You escape characters which would otherwise have a special meaning in the query. So the data which is actually stored does not contain the escape characters.

Answer (score 4):

It's *totally* ***un****safe* to insert the serialized data in the database without database-specific processing.

You should use whatever mechanism is recommended for preventing SQL injections with your chosen database access layer; making the queries safe against injections includes properly escaping the data as well, so you 'll hit two birds with one stone.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) for specific examples.

Comment: @Eugeny89: **Do not do that!** `addslashes` is not a good solution, as it will only work *most* of the time. Please take the time to read the question I linked to.

Comment: note that I'm serializing an array. How can I unescape after `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: @Eugeny89: You don't need to.